# Can I make a database call within CompletableFuture runAsync?

Tags: java, completable-future

I have a use case where I need to make a database call to retrieve some data within the `runAsync()`. I have the following method:

```
return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        // Line 1
        // Line 2 - fetch from database
        // Line 3 - use the retrieved value to set field on an object
    })
```

My question is - Is line 3 guaranteed to be executed after line 2 in sequence? Are there any gotchas I need to be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three lines in the `Runnable` will be executed sequentially, 1 then 2 then 3.

The `runAsync` applies to the `Runnable` as a whole, not to individual lines.

Would you have multiple calls to `runAsync`, you would lose the ordering guarantee.

You may use `thenApply` (and related thenXxxx) methods to keep the ordering and have different methods for the different lines.